# numpy: create a 2d numpy array where each row is filled with strings from a regular array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a regular list filled with strings of equal length:

```
['FADVAG', 'XXDXFA', 'GDXX..']
```

I want to transform it into a 2d numpy array, like the following:

```
[['F' 'A' 'D' 'V' 'A' 'G']
['X' 'X' 'D' 'X' 'F' 'A']
['G' 'D' 'X' 'X' '.' '.']]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list('astring')` splits up the characters:

```
In [187]: alist=['FADVAG', 'XXDXFA', 'GDXX..']
In [188]: arr = np.array([list(a) for a in alist])
In [189]: arr
Out[189]: 
array([['F', 'A', 'D', 'V', 'A', 'G'],
       ['X', 'X', 'D', 'X', 'F', 'A'],
       ['G', 'D', 'X', 'X', '.', '.']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

If you want to avoid a list comprehension, join them into one string and go from there

```
np.array(list(''.join(alist))).reshape(3,-1)
```

Comment: `(3,-1)` - 3 rows, -1 means `what ever works`.  Short hand for calculate the remaining dimension.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
import numpy as np
l = ['FADVAG', 'XXDXFA', 'GDXX..']
l = np.array(l)
l.reshape(len(l),-1)
```

output:

```
array([['FADVAG'],
       ['XXDXFA'],
       ['GDXX..']],
      dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: can't you able to reproduce your output as given by removing dtype

Comment: @Argus I think it is not possible to remove a dtype from numpy array as every ndarray must have a dtype